# Json to TSV from a schema

Tags: perl

I have the below json

```
{  
    "customerId":"customer-1",
    "creationTime":"1519343062945",
    "customerData": {
        "name": "customer-1-name",
        "age": "customer-1-age"
    }
}
```

I would want this to be converted to a TSV in the format below:

> customerId | creationTime | customerName | customerAge

Could this be created out of a schema, something that would define how the tsv is to be generated. May be something along the lines of..

```
<DATA DELIMITER="\t">
    <COLUMNS>
        <COLUMN ID="customerId" DATA_TYPE="STRING"/>
        <COLUMN ID="creationTime" DATA_TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <COLUMN ID="customerName" DATA_TYPE="STRING" ACCESS="customerData.name"/>
        <COLUMN ID="customerAge" DATA_TYPE="NUMBER" ACCESS="customerData.age/>
    </COLUMNS>
</DATA>
```

I randomly made up this schema. So I was wondering if there is any perl library out there that can ease the conversion of a json to tsv following the schema approach or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution -

### table.pl

```
use JSON;
use Text::Table;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
use utf8;

my $json;
{
    local $/;    #Enable 'slurp'
    open my $fh, "<", "data.json";
    $json = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}
my $json_data = decode_json($json);

my $table = Text::Table->new( "customerId", "customerName", "customerAge",
"creationTime" );

foreach my $record (@$json_data) {
    $table->load(
        [
            $record->{"customerId"},
            $record->{"customerData"}{"name"},
            $record->{"customerData"}{"age"},
            $record->{"creationTime"}
        ]
    );
}

print $table;
```

### data.json

```
[
    {
        "customerId":"001",
        "creationTime":"1519343062945",
        "customerData": {
            "name": "John Rambo",
            "age": "50"
        }
    },
    {
        "customerId":"002",
        "creationTime":"1519343062945",
        "customerData": {
            "name": "James Bond",
            "age": "45"
        }
    }
]
```

### Output

```
[root@localhost tmp]# perl table.pl
customerId  customerName  customerAge  creationTime
001         John Rambo    50           1519343062945
002         James Bond    45           1519343062945
```

You can also use [Text::ANSITable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ANSITable) for colorful tables with borders and shading options on console.

Comment: I did think of this straight forward approach. But as you can imagine this might make the code bulky and unreadable should the json data not contain certain key/values, or is too complex a json structure, etc. I wanted to know if there was some generic way by which this can be handled?

Comment: If you have such a complex json structure then you will have to flatten the hash in any case. There is no straight forward way. I am playing with huge python dictionaries these days and I have written a recursive function to flatten dictionaries/hash to have only single level key/val pairs and then print sql like tabular output

Comment: You can use [`Hash::Flatten`](http://search.cpan.org/~bbc/Hash-Flatten-1.19/lib/Hash/Flatten.pm)  module to flatten key/val pair and then its very easy without parsing keys.